# How to get images one size

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I have a quiz app created however the images are different sizes. Would it make sense to use a gridview for one image or is there a way to make sure imageview is set to the same size for different images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the ImageView size instead of use `wrap_content` just write a static number for example

`300dp`

the image will fill the ImageView no matter how big the picture is.

Comment: if its helps u please mark this as an Answer Thank you